# Unit test Ember models without application running

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js

What is the best way to unit test an Ember model without the application running in the test framework?

I couldn't find much information about how to do this. I got something like the following to work, which I think covers my needs, but is there a smarter way to do this? I'm stabbing at the dark a bit with this attempt so I'm guessing there is.

```
`import { test, moduleFor } from 'ember-qunit'`    
`import Subject from 'school/models/subject'`
`import Student from 'school/models/student'`

#Use subclass to remove relationships, add default values so set functions work.
SubjectTester = Subject.extend {
    students: null
    name: ''
}
StudentTester = Student.extend {
    subject: null
    name: ''
    height: 0
}

moduleFor('model:subject')

#Use _create to skip the store, manually set up relationships
test('Computes tallest student description', ->
    elise = StudentTester._create()
    elise.set('height', 165)
    elise.set('name', 'Elise')

    jasmine = StudentTester._create()
    jasmine.set('height', 170)
    jasmine.set('name', 'Jasmine')

    subject = SubjectTester._create()
    subject.set('name', 'Maths')
    subject.set('students', [elise, jasmine])

    equal(subject.get('tallestStudentDesc'), 'Jasmine is the tallest student in Maths')
)
```

I initially tried using reopen instead of subclassing but couldn't clean up  the changes properly...

Would it better to set up test containers and stores? Should I just use integration tests? Am I missing something really obvious? Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to avoid the store in the test? If you're worried about it creating records during testing, the created records are only stored as test fixtures. Also, you can use the helper `moduleForModel` and use `this.subject()` to get an instance of the model. If this is what you're looking for, I'd be happy to answer with some examples.

Comment: Thanks so much, all I had to do was use moduleForModel and everything worked exactly how I wanted it to... I just read the doco and it's really obvious too. I was using moduleFor in my other tests and copied it over... then it looks like I spent ages going down the wrong track!